# groupBy([]) is not working

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2

it's not giving me any errors, but the results are not grouped.

```
public function getNumberOfRetweetsOfMeByDate($fromDate, $toDate, $twId)
{
     return $this->find()->asArray()
         ->select(["to_char (insert_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as time", "count(*) as number_of_retweets_of_me"])
         ->where("twitter_id = $twId")
         ->andWhere("insert_time >= '$fromDate'::DATE")
         ->andWhere("insert_time < '$toDate'::DATE +1")
         ->groupBy(['insert_time'])
         ->having('count(*) > 0')
         ->orderBy('insert_time')
         ->all();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the alias name `time` instead of `insert_time` in the groupBy and orderBy clauses.

```
$this->find()
     ->asArray()
     ->select(["TO_CHAR(insert_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as char_time", "COUNT(*) as number_of_retweets_of_me"])
     ->where("twitter_id = $twId")
     ->andWhere("insert_time >= '$fromDate'::DATE")
     ->andWhere("insert_time < '$toDate'::DATE +1")
     ->groupBy(['char_time'])
     ->having('COUNT(*) > 0')
     ->orderBy('char_time')
     ->all();
```

Another tip: try avoiding mysql keywords for field names or aliases which could cause problems in other situations.